# Detect what this unknown device is (on Intel LPC Interface Controller)

Tags: device-manager

An unknown device is detected in all the computers/laptops we buy from a specific vendor.
The vendor himself does not have any idea of what this device could be.

The vendor and I searched the hardware physically for something unknown to us, but found nothing. Any help in identifying what this device could be?

```
Device Type: Other devices
Manufacturer: Unknown
Location: on Intel(R) 82801FBM LPC Interface Controller - 2641
```

**Note:** Disabling and enabling this device does not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a TPM?

In `devmgmt.msc` you should be able to find out what resources (I/O ports, memory addresses, IRQs) it's taking up.  Based on those you may be able to find out what device it is.  I don't think LPC has vendor/device ID strings like the PCI bus...

Comment: so kindly guide on how to know what device this is?

Answer (score 0):

Shamelessly referring to [my own post on identifying a graphics card](https://superuser.com/questions/607958/cannot-find-ecs-945gct-drivers):

Use the same method to get the PCI ID of the LPC controller rather than the graphics card in the example below.

[image]

Fill in the PCI ID in [this database](http://www.pcidatabase.com/) or in a similar one.

Then hopefully find the driver for your [LPC controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_Pin_Count)