# Cannot find ECS 945GCT drivers

Tags: windows-xp, drivers

I reinstalled windows xp sp3
In device manager I have two yellow marks:
- PCI Simple Communication Controller
- SM Bus Controller

CPU-Z says my MB is `ECS 945GCT-M2` chipset `i945G`.

I visited so many sites to find the drivers - no success.

Any help, pls.

Comment: What are the PCI hardware IDs for these devices?  
( From device manager, go to the failed device. Right click, properties (now at the page with "Device status, this device is ... (code..)". Go to the tab "Details" and change "Device description" to "Hardware ID". Post those. )

Comment: Once you got that ID, used sites such as [this site](http://www.pcidatabase.com/) to determine which device is is and to help locate the driver.

Comment: @Hennes, you helped me. Please, post your comment as answer, so I could accept it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have unknown hardware which is 20 years or less old you usually can get the PCI device ID. This will help you indentify which hardware it is, rather than a generic *PCI Simple Communication Controller* or similar.

For unix like OS'ses such as FreeBSd, Linux or OS X use `lspci` or `pciconf`.

For windows you can use the hardware ID tab in the device manager.

To start the device manager either go to [start] [run] and type `devmgmt.msc` or right click on the [my computer] icon on your desktop, select "manage" and click on the device manager option.

(Screenshots from win 7. It is similar in XP).

[image: Starting the device manager via start run devmgmt.msc]

[image: Starting the device manager via my computer and manage]

From device manager:

- Go to the device you want to find the hardware ID from.
- Right click on it and select "properties".
- Go to the tab "Details" and change "Device description" to "Hardware ID".

[image: Image of the harware IDs in the device management screen]

Note the value with the lines like this one: `PCI\ven1002&dev_6898&subsyst_0b`...

Search for that in the internet or use a site like http://www.pcidatabase.com/.

Note that these IDs have a fixed format. The first number will always indicate the manufacturer. In this case that is ATI/AMD (ATI was bought out by AMD).

[image]

The remaining numbers indicate all the detaiils, often down to the revision number.