# I can't add a fingerprint to Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, fingerprint

I am trying to set up my fingerprint to log on in Windows 7 32-bit on my Sony VGN-SR590GPB laptop. I also experience the same problem on my other laptop with the same setup, a Sony VGN-Z56TG. I tried going to Control Panel -> Biometric Devices and then clicking on the option to use my fingerprint with Windows. This opens up Internet Explorer and links me to http://tiny.cc/ts32bit, on which it gives me a "this page can't be displayed" error. (When I open the link in CoolNovo instead of Internet Explorer, it appears to go to http://webimages.authentec.com/store/uFMA/ufma-32bit.html, which also gives me a DNS error.) I can't find the drivers for my PC online (only drivers for Windows 7 64-bit and Windows XP are displayed). Should I try installing the Windows XP drivers (which are 32-bit), or is it impossible to use the fingerprint sensor in this configuration?

Comment: What does the Sony site or the user manual suggest? So, you've looked in [Sony's eSupport](http://esupport.sony.com/US/p/select-system.pl?PRODTYPE=24) for your series and model? I don't know what model you have, but I was able to find some drivers for finger print sensor listed under `Security`.

Comment: @CharlieRB Which one should I install? I see either Windows 7 64-bit or Windows XP.

Comment: What came with your computer?

Comment: @CharlieRB I actually don't know. I bought it from someone who installed Linux on it and formatted the disc, and then I used the included recovery discs to install Windows XP on it. Then, I upgraded it to Windows 7 Professional 32-bit using someone else's install disc and the product key on the bottom of the machine.

Comment: Not having the OEM install (Win XP) or the properly specified upgrade (Win 7 64) puts you in a rough spot. You can try either one, as there is no guarantee either will work. If you can find a Vista version it might work. If none work, email Sony support. Good luck.

Comment: @CharlieRB I remember now. The PC shipped with Windows 7 64-bit, but the included recovery discs are for Windows XP.

Comment: @CharlieRB What about the other laptop?

Comment: If you have the product key for the Windows 7 64 then install it so you can use the device with the proper drivers. That's as simple as it gets. Otherwise, you will continue to have driver compatibility issues.

Comment: @CharlieRB I don't have an install disc, though...

Comment: Check out this post. It will help you with that. http://superuser.com/q/78761/97028

Comment: @gparyani Did you get it working? If so, how? Via some driver for win7-32 or did you install win7 x64? If you did not get it working: How is the bio reader connected? Can you list [the hardware ID of the reader](http://superuser.com/questions/607958/cannot-find-ecs-945gct-drivers)?

Comment: @Hennes The hardware ID is `USB\VID_147E&PID_1000&REV_0033`.

Comment: Some [googling on the HW ID](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=usb+vid_147e%26pid_1000%26rev_0033+windows+7) reveals that device `USB\VID_147E&PID_1000&REV_0033` is an UPEK reader made by AuthenTec.

AuthenTec got [bought by Apple](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2012/07/apple-stepping-up-mobile-payments-security-with-authentec-buyout/) and their old website no longer exists.

Comment: Some more searching yields a lot of third party (and thus untrusted) driver download sites and link such as [this one from Lenovo for AuthenTec TrueSuite Fingerprint Software for 32-bit Windows](http://support.lenovo.com/en_GB/downloads/detail.page?DocID=DS030584) which **might** actually work.  Can you test that one?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue with my HP laptop, which had been reimaged with a regular (non-HP) Win7 install.  There are two parts needed for this puzzle, the hardware drivers (which Windows will pull down automatically), and the application to use the hardware (what you're being directed to the 404 authentec.com site to fetch).  Going to HP's driver selection for the laptop, I had to download HP's ProtectTools suite, which includes the application software.  You'll have to hunt down Sony's equivalent through their support site.

Comment: Ah, but in my case, only Windows 7 64-bit and Windows XP are listed as two possible operating systems to install on. Mine is Windows 7 32-bit. Which one should I choose?

Comment: Sorry haven't been back on this site for...yikes...long time.  Back in '14 I would have said try the XP version...now, I'm not so sure.  Hope you worked something out.  I no longer have the laptop mentioned above, killed it by spilling hot beef soup on it while it was booting. >.<

Answer (score 2):

Here is the links to AuthenTec TrueSuite Fingerprint Software from Lenovo website:

Windows 7, 32-bit (tiny.cc/ts32bit)
https://support.lenovo.com/downloads/ds030584
Windows 7, 64-bit (tiny.cc/ts64bit)
https://support.lenovo.com/downloads/ds030585

Comment: Sony suspended all Windows 7 support since 2021. The Lenovo 32 bit version works on my Vaio VGN-SZ53B/B though at login no graphic is displayed to make me aware that biometrics works and is ready also for login. I have to know / remember this. No idea if the reason for this is because I installed the Lenovo Version.