# Video Adapter needs an update, but where?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, video, updates

I just recently got an compaq presario which had windows xp installed on it. I decided to put a bigger hard drive on it and upgrade it to windows 7.

When i did this, it did not recognize my sound card or my Ethernet adapter. Eventually I fixed my sound card by installing a more updated driver and same for my eithernet adapter.

Later on I noticed that I could not put the computer to sleep or run very many programs because of the video adapter. I went to that in the device manager section in control panel, but every time I click update it finds one on the internet (sis760)but this error comes up while installing it. I think this is because the update is for windows xp because that is what I was running before but im not exactly sure.
[image: This is the error i am getting]

anything helps...Ps would you reccomend a Bios update...If so where should I get that from?...Thanks,
Hunter

Comment: In the second window, go to `Details` tab and look for the `Device Instance Path` in the combobox, and tell us here, Eg: http://i.stack.imgur.com/oYeOS.jpg.

Comment: [A post with some more pictures in it](http://superuser.com/questions/607958/cannot-find-ecs-945gct-drivers) (and that post itself is a duplicate, you can also follow the duplicate of XXX link).

Comment: Simply stated there isn't an update.  I don't even believe there exists a specific device driver for Windows 7 thus your stuck with the generic display driver

Comment: it shows PCI\VEN_1039&DEV_6330&SUBSYS_2A06103C&REV_00\4&F74CB32&0&0008

Comment: Try installing latest XP 32-bit driver (version 6.14.10.3930, released in October 2010) which can be found here: http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/ScopedViewRedirect.aspx?updateid=0444e07e-c3a9-4eb9-8075-f36fd290544b Extract the `.cab` archive and update it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I unsterstood that you installed the sound card and ethernet adapter drivers through Windows. Is that correct?

That being said, Windows seems to be unable to find the driver for the video card. You should search yourself through the website of the manufacturer of the video card of your notebook (google like this: name of the video card + drivers).

If you already did that, perhaps the video card just doesn't support Windows 7. You said that it is a old laptop so that is possible.

Comment: I did install it through windows, and at one point windows update had the update for it but that failed also and now I cant seem to find it there anymore. If I search the windows catalog, It comes up With a bunch of them, but some of Them dont seem to work.

Comment: I will try googleing it though. Do you think It may be failing due to the Bios?

Comment: @Hunter I don't think BIOS has anything to do with it but I can't rule it out. Try getting a driver for the manufacturer website first.

Comment: ok I tried with microsoft but they have failed and most are saying that they are built for windows xp 64 bit. http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=sis

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I'd bet your system was manufactured around 2003?  If you look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_Integrated_Systems) you'll notice there isn't any listing of an SiS PC chipset since 2003.

Pretty much any motherboard these days will have Intel integrated graphics/chipset, or something with ATI if it's an AMD CPU based system.  SiS probably hasn't made any integrated graphics hardware since 2003.  Meaning you probably will not find Vista drivers for your SiS integrated VGA adapter,  let alone Windows 7.

Since I'm fairly certain this is a 32-bit system, you may be able to get the driver to install if you download the XP version and try going into right click -> Properties -> Compatibility and set it to Windows XP.  Good luck.

Certainly it has a PCI slot free at the very least, or even an AGP?  You should look into getting a PCI or AGP video card (they'd be dirt cheap now anyway).

Comment: I tried that but I still could not get it to work. It actially is a 64 bit system. maby ill just have to buy a new adapter.