# Which devices are (0F18, 0F12, 00BD) these IDs for? All share the same Vendor ID (8086), i.e. Intel

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, drivers, lenovo-laptop, pci

It is a *Lenovo G50-70* Notebook PC. I reinstalled Windows 8.1 on it. The official website does not provide **all** the necessary drivers required for the Device Manager to calm down. Yellows still persist. One says PCI...Encryption/Decryption, one Unknown device, and another yellow yuck.

Comment: Might be worth a shot to try with `lspci` on a Linux live system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some quick googling shows that:

- Device 8086:0f18 is the [Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine](http://pci-ids.ucw.cz/read/PC/8086/0f18)
- Device 8060:0f12 is a "ValleyView SMBus Controller"

Useful links:

- [PCI Vendor and Device Lists](http://www.devicekb.com/)
- [PCI ID Repository](http://pci-ids.ucw.cz/read/PC/8086)
- [Cannot find ECS 945GCT drivers](https://superuser.com/questions/607958/cannot-find-ecs-945gct-drivers) (win7 based, but with some explanation which is true for any OS).