# Can't detect LAN and Audio on Windows XP Professional SP3

Tags: windows, networking, windows-xp, lan, sp3

I have **Windows XP Professional SP3** and just after its installation, I go to the browser - internet explorer to download any programs. The cable of *LAN* was plugged in the computer, but there wasn't an internet connection.

I opened the Task Manager and check if there is any network connection, and there wasn't! I check if my Router works, and it worked on the other's computers!

I check in Device Manager and there I tried to uninstall the drivers for the network adapter. It only says that it cannot uninstall them and a restart will be required. I tried clearing the registry with Wise Registry Cleaner, but nothing helped yet. I searched in forums and etc... **Nothing helps!** Or I can't find the true solution.

The same with the audio!

Here is a photo of the LAN drivers:

[image]

**Any help will be *MUCH* appreciated!!**

**Thanks!**

Comment: Some information about your network card and its current driver will help.

Comment: Yep I added an image:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnZNh.jpg

Comment: I see no recognisable network card in that image. What is the PCI-ID on the other PCI bridge device? (See https://superuser.com/questions/607958/cannot-find-ecs-945gct-drivers for how to find that). If that turns out to be the NIC then you will need to download the right drivers on another computer and somehow move them over (e.g. via USB pendrive, CDROM, floppy, ...)

Comment: and don't capture screenshots with a camera. That's what `print screen` on the keyboard for

Comment: Print screen doesn't work at my PC!

Comment: I will try your way (Hennes)!

Comment: [Hennes](https://superuser.com/users/121352/hennes), your way is not working. I'm sorry about that!

Comment: Thanks to all methods, but still absolutely nothing helps! I'm wondering what I should do!

Comment: **IMPORTANT:** Can this problem be solved if I reinstall Windows XP?

Comment: So many devices are missing their drivers, that it looks like XP was reinstalled once already. Reinstalling it again might only result in more missing drivers. And there is no LAN device at all. If you think there is a network adapter in the computer, it should show up, since such adapters are rarely undetectable, even by a an antique such as XP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way:

I just get DriverPack offline from its official site, put it on a flash and use it to solve all other driver bugs on my Windows XP. 
Thanks to Harrymc too. He let me in the right direction!